# What's the function $n_{\chi[0,1/n]}$?

Tags: convex-analysis

On one paper I saw the function:

$$f_n=n_{\chi[0,1/n]}$$

What is this function?

I read that it's $n$ multiplied by the characteristic function on set $[0,1/n]$.
But since $f_n$ in this case is supposed to defined for

$f \in L^1([0,1])$ s.t. $\int_0^1 f(t)dt=1$

then I don't see how $f_n$ necessarily stays bounded inside this.

Comment: have you computed $\int_0^1 f_n(t) dt$ ?

Comment: @mercio But what does $n_{\chi[0,1/n]}$ mean? Does it mean that $\chi$ modulates $n$ so that $n$ appears only when $\chi$ gets value $1$ or what? Then the integral is probably equal to $|_0^1 \frac{1}{2}t^2=\frac{1}{2}(1^2-0^2)=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: It is $n$ multiplied with the characteristic function of $[0, \frac 1n]$. Though are you sure the $\chi$ is a subscript of $n$ ??

Comment: @mercio What does the characteristic function characterize? Since it's "if $x \in A$, then $1$, otherwise $0$", but what's $x$?

Comment: $\chi_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $\chi_A(x) = 0$ if $x \notin A$

Answer (score 1):

Wait, there's a misunderstanding here!

Let:
$$f_n:=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$$
and also let:
$$f:=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$$
Then, it is clear that:
$$I_n:=\int_0^1f_nd\lambda=\int_0^{1/n}ndt=1$$
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, every $f_n$ seperately **is bounded**.

However, the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is not **uniformly bounded!**. Moreover, 
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\infty & x=0\\
0 & x\neq0
\end{array}\right.$$
which is clearly not bounded.

Also note that:
$$\int fd\lambda=0$$